# How to Prompt user if IE's protect mode is turning on using C#?

Tags: internet-explorer, uac, toolbar, prompt

I'm writing IE's toolbar. In my situation, I need to change information in myapp.dll.config and use ShellWindows, both of them not allowed when IE's Protected Mode enabled.

So I want to prompt user if IE's Protected Mode is ON.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since your code is in IE's process you can call [IEIsProtectedModeProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537316%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get the protect mode status.